# Script error -> Popup "my logins" in network profile on stackexchange does not open

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, login, network-profile

I just tried to open the popup "my logins" in my network profile on stackexchange, but when I click the button the popup does not open and the "loading dots" are displayed and nothing happens.

I have opened the Developer tools of my Browser (Chrome 25.0.1364.172) and the console logged an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bindMovablePopups'
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.globalEval jquery.min.js:2
bp jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.append jquery.min.js:3
f.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
$.ajax.success jehof:56
n jquery.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was (unsuprisingly, given the error message), making the popup movable (i.e. draggable). This change was made to the Q&A sites recently, but we overlooked that the same popup is also used on stackexchange.com, which didn't have the corresponding JavaScript functionality. It does now, and the popup works again. Thanks for noticing!